# Connecting to MySQL database and creating array to use elsewhere with Swift

Tags: ios, mysql, swift

I am learning Swift and trying to pull data from local host MySQL database. Following some tutorials I was able to get this:

```
   func getInfo()  {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/service.php")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        var d = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var arr = d!.componentsSeparatedByString("<") 
        var dataweneed:NSString = arr[0] as! NSString
        if let data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataweneed.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSArray {

            self.tableData = data
            println(data)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

This is in the view controller file.

I call the function form the viewDidLoad. I declare a variable tableData:NSArray = [] at the top, and I can see the data via the println(data) inside the function, but if I try to use tableData outside the function, it is empty.

How can I get the data that is inside variable 'data' to be able to use outside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload your tableView when you get data from server this way:

```
func getInfo()  {
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/service.php")
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    var d = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var arr = d!.componentsSeparatedByString("<") 
    var dataweneed:NSString = arr[0] as! NSString
    if let data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataweneed.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSArray {

        self.tableData = data
        println(data)

        // Reload tableView here.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Hope this will help.